# can't call PHP script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to run/call a PHP file that is going to update a database.

Chrome is giving me this error: [image]

I'm using this code for my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="descriptioninput">
    <input type="number" id="budgetin">
    <input type="number" id="budgetout">
    <button type="button" onclick="addToDB()">Add to database</button>

    <script>
        function addToDB()
        {
            var descriptioninput = document.getElementById('descriptioninput').value;
            var budgetin = document.getElementById('budgetin').value;
            var budgetout = document.getElementById('budgetout').value;

            $.ajax ( {
                TYPE: 'POST',
                url: 'addtodb.php',
                data:{descriptioninput:descriptioninput, budgetin:budgetin, budgetout:budgetout},
                success:function (data) {
                    // Completed successfully
                    alert('success!');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried to place the code in the `<head>` element and specify `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: You have not included `jQuery`..add this `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You forgot to reference the `jquery` in your code***. Either add it locally or use ***CDN*** :

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to jQuery then remeber: javascript is case sensitive. Change `TYPE` to `type`

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addtodb.php',
    data:{descriptioninput:descriptioninput, budgetin:budgetin, budgetout:budgetout},
    success:function (data) {
        // Completed successfully
        alert('success!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This function `$.ajax()` belongs to to Javascript library called jQuery, and you should include this library in your head block.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```